# Is there a way to use explicit instantiation to set member variables by type

Tags: c++, templates

Simplified example of what I am trying to do:

If I have a class:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : numericType(false){};

private:
    bool numericType;
}
```

And I want it to set awesomeType to true if T is an numeric type but false otherwise.  Can I do this using explicit instantiation?  Where each type I want to set numericType to true is explicitly instantiated and sets it to true, while all other types are not explicitly instantiated so remain false?

If not, how would you go about this?

Side Note:  I cannot use C++11 thanks to my intel compiler.

Comment: take a look at `<type_traits>`

Comment: Please elaborate what explicit/implicit things you want to do

Comment: @DieterLücking I purely want to change the value of numericType to true for the basic numeric types of (int, float, and double).  So I want those types to have a different constructor.

Comment: @Tim <type_traits> appears to only be in C++11, which my intel compiler does not support.  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: There is a boost version of it also: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @Tim thanks, I'll look into the Boost solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't use C++11, then you can follow the advice of the others but with Boost instead of STL:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html

There is not really any magic here though. Just template specialization. You would be able to implement it on your own even if it is cumbersome.

Answer (score 4):

There is an existing type trait you can use to identify arithmetic types: From `<type_traits>`, the boolean [`std::is_arithmetic<T>::value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) indicates whether `T` is an arithmetic type.

Since this is a property of the *type*, and not of any particular *object* of this type, you should not make this boolean a non-static data member. At best, it should be a static, constant data member, but you might just as well not bother and use the trait directly when needed.

Comment: @user1364540: It is trivial to write this yourself. Let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly what is done in [std::is_arithmetic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic).

I've just seen that you're not allowed to use C++11... 
Try boost type traits [is_arithmetic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_arithmetic.html).

The standard "stole" this one from boost.